# Is there a correct method or quick way for changing the name of my application/solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I have made my application, just wondering if there was a way I could change the name of my   application/.sln . Because Obviously the namespaces will need to changed etc.

But I was just curious whether theres a correct proceedure/easy method to go about it?

Answer (score 2):

You can rename any project by right-clicking the project in Solution Explorer and select Rename. But this doesn’t change the physical folder name. To change the physical folder name, first right-select “Open Folder in Window Explorer”, then close the solution (File> Close Solution), then rename the folder that contains the project (the folder in which the *.csproj file resides). When you reopen the solution, VS won’t be able to load the project. To fix this, remove the stale project entry in Solution Explorer, then right-select the Properties of the solution > Add > Existing Project and navigate to select the *.csproj file.

Caveat: The namespaces for your classes will stay the same as they were before the rename.

Comment: Renaming projects and solutions is pretty painful. Pro tip: Make sure you save a copy of the files before you start monkeying with them, either in source control or just physically copying the folder. I usually close Visual Studio entirely and use Notepad++ to do a Find/Replace in the entire directory. There are lots of little places where the project name is used--class namespaces, build assembly names, AppManifest.xaml, etc. It's not hard--just a little tedious.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy whay, but you can use Find and replace to do so.